# "Cart block" and "Add to cart" button disappear Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Both Cart block on top of my webpage and the "Add to cart" button in each product disappear. This happens on every page of my website and this happen all out of a sudden (pardon me, if I could recall/ narrow down what change I made is causing this then I wouldn't ask a question here)

What I have tried to troubleshoot/ resolve the problem:

- Verified that "Cart block" v1.2 module is installed and enabled (also tried disable & enable again, reset, uninstall and install again)
- Verified that under "Modules" >> "Positions", "Cart block" is there under both "Pages header" and "Top of pages"
- Verified that there is no Javascript files with 404 error
- Verified that there is no HTML code at all for the the cart block or the "Add to cart" button so CSS issues are irrelevant `<section id="header_user" class="blockuserinfo-cart header-box"></section>`

  - Switched back to default theme
    but absolutely no luck

I'm pretty sure this is something trivial that I missed.
Please help because my site cannot work without the cart functionalities obviously.

Thanks,

My Prestashop version is 1.5.5.0

Below is my Smarty debug log FYI:

```
Smarty Debug Console - Total Time 0.09338 included templates & config files (load time in seconds)/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/feeder/feederHeader.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00011) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/paypal/views/templates/hook/paypal.js(compile 0.00000) (render 0.00009) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blocklanguages/blocklanguages.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00031) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks-header.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00010) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blocksearch/blocksearch-top.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00008) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00035) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00010) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00120) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockcms/blockcms.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00031) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockadvertising/blockadvertising.tpl(compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00011) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00047) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blocknewproducts/blocknewproducts.tpl(compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00011) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/paypal/views/templates/hook/column.tpl(compile 0.00000) (render 0.00015) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockwishlist/blockwishlist.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00017) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/homeslider/homeslider.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00012) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00015) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/editorial/editorial.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00010) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockmyaccountfooter/blockmyaccountfooter.tpl(compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00010) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/modules/blockcontactinfos/blockcontactinfos.tpl(compile 0.00000) (render 0.00000) (cache 0.00013) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/index.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00011) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/layout.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00105) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/header.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00036) (cache 0.00000) 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/footer.tpl (compile 0.00000) (render 0.00009) (cache 0.00000) assigned template variables $HOOK_FOOTER Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = " <!-- MODULE Block footer -->..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $HOOK_HEADER Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = " <link rel="alternate" type="applicat..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $HOOK_HOME Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "<!-- Module HomeSlider --> <script ty..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = " <!-- Block Viewed products --> <se..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "<!-- MODULE Block new products --> <..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $HOOK_TOP Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = " <!-- Block languages module --> <s..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $PS_ALLOW_MOBILE_DEVICE Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $PS_CATALOG_MODE Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $PS_SHOP_NAME Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "NiuNiu"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "1"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $SCRIPT_NAME Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/index.php"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Global" $add_prod_display Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 1
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $b2b_enable Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = false
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $base_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $base_dir_ssl Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $base_uri Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $cart Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Cart Object (23)
   ->id = 6
   ->id_shop_group = "0"
   ->id_shop = "1"
   ->id_address_delivery = "5"
   ->id_address_invoice = "5"
   ->id_currency = "1"
   ->id_customer = "2"
   ->id_guest = "21"
   ->id_lang = "1"
   ->recyclable = "0"
   ->gift = "0"
   ->gift_message = ""
   ->mobile_theme = "0"
   ->date_add = "2013-10-20 14:32:18"
   ->secure_key = "63c9bc62096e6e078d1e5377ac39e35e"
   ->id_carrier = "0"
   ->date_upd = "2013-10-27 11:36:53"
   ->checkedTos = false
   ->pictures = null
   ->textFields = null
   ->delivery_option = ""
   ->allow_seperated_package = "0"
   ->id_shop_list = null
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $cart_qties Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 0
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $come_from Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/en/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $conditions Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "1"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $content_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $content_only Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 0
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $cookie Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Cookie Object (0)
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $css_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/themes/f..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $css_files Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (28)
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/grid_prestashop.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/global.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/carriercompare/style.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css=> "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocknewproducts/blocknewproducts.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blockuserinfo/blockuserinfo.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blockmyaccountfooter/blockmyaccount.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocklanguages/blocklanguages.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blockcms/blockcms.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocktags/blocktags.css => "all"
  /niuniu/js/jquery/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/product_list.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocksearch/blocksearch.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/crossselling/crossselling.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/productscategory/productscategory.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blockcontactinfos/blockcontactinfos.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocklink/blocklink.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/productcomments/productcomments.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.css => "all"
  /niuniu/modules/paypal/css/paypal.css => "all"
  /niuniu/modules/editorial/editorial.css => "all"
  /niuniu/js/jquery/plugins/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.css => "all"
  /niuniu/modules/sendtoafriend/sendtoafriend.css => "all"
  /niuniu/modules/blockwishlist/blockwishlist.css => "all"
  /niuniu/themes/fashionbird/css/modules/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css => "all"
  /niuniu/modules/homeslider/bx_styles.css => "all"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $currencies Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (1)
  0 => Array (12)
    id_currency => "1"
    name => "Dollar"
    iso_code => "SGD"
    iso_code_num => "702"
    sign => "$"
    blank => "1"
    format => "1"
    decimals => "1"
    conversion_rate => "1.000000"
    deleted => "0"
    active => "1"
    id_shop => "1"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $currency Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Currency Object (14)
   ->id = 1
   ->name = "Dollar"
   ->iso_code = "SGD"
   ->iso_code_num = "702"
   ->sign = "$"
   ->blank = "1"
   ->conversion_rate = "1.000000"
   ->deleted = "0"
   ->format = "1"
   ->decimals = "1"
   ->active = "1"
   ->prefix = "$ "
   ->suffix = ""
   ->id_shop_list = null
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $customerName Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "Eric Nguyen"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $display_footer Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $display_header Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $display_tax_label Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $errors Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (0)
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $favicon_url Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/img/favicon.ico"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $hide_left_column Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = false
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $hide_right_column Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = false
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $id_cart Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 6
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $id_cgv Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "3"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $id_currency_cookie Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 1
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_cat_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/c/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_col_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/co/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/themes/f..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_lang_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/l/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_manu_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/m/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_prod_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/p/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_ps_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_ship_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/s/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_store_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/st/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_sup_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/img/su/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $img_update_time Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "1382845757"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $js_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/themes/f..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $js_files Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (14)
  0 => "/niuniu/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
  1 => "/niuniu/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.easi..."
  2 => "/niuniu/js/tools.js"
  3 => "/niuniu/modules/carriercompare/carrie..."
  4 => "/niuniu/js/jquery/plugins/autocomplet..."
  5 => "/niuniu/modules/crossselling/js/cross..."
  6 => "/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/js/modules..."
  7 => "/niuniu/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.seri..."
  8 => "/niuniu/js/jquery/plugins/jgrowl/jque..."
  9 => "/niuniu/modules/blockwishlist/js/ajax..."
  10 => "/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/js/modules..."
  11 => "/niuniu/themes/fashionbird/js/modules..."
  12 => "/niuniu/modules/homeslider/js/jquery...."
  13 => "/niuniu/modules/homeslider/js/homesli..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $lang_iso Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "en"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $languages Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (3)
  0 => Array (10)
    id_lang => "1"
    name => "English (United States)"
    active => "1"
    iso_code => "en"
    language_code => "en"
    date_format_lite => "Y-m-d"
    date_format_full => "Y-m-d H:i:s"
    is_rtl => "0"
    id_shop => "1"
    shops => Array (1)
      1 => true
  1 => Array (10)
    id_lang => "2"
    name => "Chinese-Traditional"
    active => "1"
    iso_code => "tw"
    language_code => "tw"
    date_format_lite => "Y-m-d"
    date_format_full => "Y-m-d H:i:s"
    is_rtl => "0"
    id_shop => "1"
    shops => Array (1)
      1 => true
  2 => Array (10)
    id_lang => "3"
    name => "Chinese-Simplified"
    active => "1"
    iso_code => "zh"
    language_code => "zh"
    date_format_lite => "Y-m-d"
    date_format_full => "Y-m-d H:i:s"
    is_rtl => "0"
    id_shop => "1"
    shops => Array (1)
      1 => true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $link Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Link Object (2)
   ->protocol_link
   ->protocol_content
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $logged Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = true
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $logo Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/modules/paypal/img/logos/GB_v..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $logo_image_height Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "36"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $logo_image_width Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "300"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $logo_url Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/img/logo.jpg?1382845757"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $mail_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/mails/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $meta_description Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "Shop powered by PrestaShop"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $meta_keywords Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = ""
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $meta_language Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "en-tw-zh"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $meta_title Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "NiuNiu"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $mobile_device Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = false
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $modules_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/modules/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $navigationPipe Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = ">"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $opc Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = false
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $page_name Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "index"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $pic_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/upload/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $priceDisplay Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 0
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $priceDisplayPrecision Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 2
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $request Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "http://localhost:8888/niuniu/en/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $request_uri Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/niuniu/en/"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $roundMode Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 2
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $shop_name Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "NiuNiu"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $show_taxes Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 0
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $static_token Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "e9169799f715848b8dd0593eef59e057"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $template Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = " <!-- Module HomeSlider --> <script t..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $time Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 1382847430
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $token Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "233105f0dd03355c312d2f6b4cd504f5"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $tpl_dir Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/niuniu/them..."
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $use_taxes Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 1
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" $vat_management Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = 0
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root" assigned config file variables (outer template scope)
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same problem and spent days searching for a fix.

What fixed it for me was:

- go to Prefrences/products
- turn "Catalog mode" OFF
- then save.

Also make sure all you hooks are reset for cart block.

Comment: Thank you! This saved another hours of searching for the solution :)

Comment: you save my day as well

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was:

go to Prefrences/products
turn "Catalog mode" OFF
then save.

It repared my paypal issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the exact same problem.

In my case the solution was that the `Available for order` checkbox was somehow ticked off on the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Is this where it is there and then it animates out of sight so you cant see it? if so this is because they rather stupidly decided that the control that makes the cart appear and disappear is actually attached to a completely different module entirely, the user info module. So if you roll over that module the cart appears as it does in the default theme if they are both installed.